# Cannot read property 'string' of undefined When using any external library in react

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

So, I'm using couple of external libraries in react like `react-markdown` , `react-bootstrap`.

All of sudden, this libraries started giving me above error in unit tests. Everything works fine with the web-app, but only unit tests are failing.

Any idea what could be the issue here ? Any help is appreciated.

```
FAIL  src/containers/xyz/__tests__/xyz-test.js

Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-markdown/src/react-markdown.js:43:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/xyz/index.js:4:48)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/containers/xyz/__tests__/xyz-test.js:2:41)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

And this is how my component `xyz` lokks like on line 4.

```
import { inJest } from '../../config/Env'
import shallowCompare from 'react-addons-shallow-compare'
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot read property 'string' of undefined When using any external library in react

This is due to a recent update in react. Update `react-markdown`. It used to use `React.proptypes` : https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown/blob/be588dd1aaf51a46f6c2160e32329dc1f1e90543/src/react-markdown.js#L7

The latest version should have it fixed